# Scope topic query when ordering by comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to set the order for Topic index by most recent Comment. This is working:

```
Topic.joins(:comments).order("comments.created_at desc")
```

But it lists the Topics more than one time.

Is there a way to limit the times each topic is displayed to one?

Comment: If you need to do this a lot, I'd store a last comment date right on the topic model. And index it.

Comment: have you tried to add `.group(:id)` ?

Comment: @MrYoshiji, that gives an error `PG::Error: ERROR:  column reference "id" is ambiguous`

Comment: @BrianMcDonough try with `group('topics.id')`

Comment: @MrYoshiji tried that out and got this: `PG::Error: ERROR:  column "comments.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ...table_type" = 'Topic' GROUP BY topics.id ORDER BY comments.c...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "topics".* FROM "topics" INNER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."commentable_id" = "topics"."id" AND "comments"."commentable_type" = 'Topic' GROUP BY topics.id ORDER BY comments.created_at desc LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Your suggestion is the right way to do it in the long-term, but how would I save? Using a hidden field in the comments form? Using an after_save method in the comment model?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Denormalizing the data like that is sometimes the only way to get the performance you need, but optimization like that should always be done when it's needed, not before. It really depends on how large the dataset is. For most small to mid-size apps, joining and grouping is going to be fast enough.

Comment: @MrTheWalrus: I started with an "if", see? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev So you did. I stand corrected. (Although it's worth pointing out that by 'do this a lot', we mean 'for large datasets' rather than 'in many places in the code'.)

Comment: @MrTheWalrus: yes, large datasets and/or high throughput.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most elegant way I found to solve the problem is to add `touch` to the polymorphic association in the comment model:

`belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true, touch: true`

If you're not using a polymorphic association, you can use:

`belongs_to :topic, touch: true`

Then, all I had to do was change the default scope in the topic model to `updated_at`

`default_scope order: 'topics.updated_at DESC'`

Adding `touch` to comment means that every time a comment is added to topic, it updates the updated_at column in topics.

In the controller I am using:

`@topics = Topic.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 20, :page => params[:page])`

`Topic.all` or something else could work there as well.

Thanks to my super friend Alain for pointing this out to me.

Comment: That is a pretty cool solution. It has a few implicit assumptions to be aware of, though - anything else that updates the Topic model will *also* change `updated_at`, so, for instance, if a Topic is edited, that will move it to the top of your sorted results. If you're ok with that, though, this seems like a nicely efficient way to get this functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, what's happening is this: When you join the comments, you get one database row for each comment, which (if there are multiple comments on a Topic), means multiple copies of each topic record.

To fix this, you'll need to use grouping, so that there's only one result per topic. The thing to group by is the id of the model you're returning (`topics.id`). Now, there's more to it - because there are still multiple comments per result, there are also multiple created_at values for each, and thus (in order to sort by it, as you do) you need to tell the database which one to use.

This is done with an aggregation function of some sort. I'm guessing you want the most recent comment to be the one that determines the order. If that's true, the code will be something like this:

```
Topic.joins(:comments).select('topics.*, max(comments.created_at) as last_comment').group('topics.id').order('last_comment desc')
```

The custom select includes the usual data that you need (everything about the Topic object - `topics.*`) and also an aggregate function (`max()`, which as the name suggests returns the largest of the possible values. ) used on the creation date of the comments. More recent dates are larger, so this will be the most recent comment's creation datestamp. That result is aliased as `last_comment` (using `as`), so you can refer to it in the `.order` call.