# Order by Latest Comment or Latest Topic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

I was successful in implementing a query to display topics in an index, ordered by the most recent comment using this:

```
Topic.joins(:comments).
      select('topics.*, max(comments.created_at) as last_comment').
      group('topics.id').
      order('last_comment desc')
```

However, that introduced another issue. New topics are now appearing at the bottom of the list.

Is there a way to include or join the topic created_at date along with the comment created_at date in the query? Is `flatten` the right way to do it?

Comment: try using `order('last_comment desc, topics.created_at desc')`

Comment: Did you mean `order('last_comment desc, topics.created_at desc')` @SybariteManoj ?

Comment: I found another really great way to do this, using `touch` and `updated_at` Check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587140/scope-topic-query-when-ordering-by-comments/14590822#14590822

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to you use

```
Topic.joins(:comments).order('comments.created_at desc')
```

In that case your topics will order by latest comment date